# Command for deleting temporary files ending with ~

Tags: bash

Many days ago, I found this useful bash alias (contents of my **~/.bash_aliases**)

```
# aliases

# finds temporary files ending with '~' and deletes them
alias rm~='find . -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f'
```

Now I tried to use `rm~` after `cd` to some directory containing 3 files ending in `~`

I got this error in terminal, and files did not get deleted

```
find: paths must precede expression: 1n.in~
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Also when I tried `rm~` from `/home/me`, it seems to be doing nothing. Or it might be taking a lot of time.

Please tell me why am I getting error, and how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your bash alias is not well written (the single quotes are not well used). Instead it should be:

```
alias rm~='find . -name "*~" -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f'
```

Now, I personally don't like useless uses of pipes and `xargs`, so your alias would be better written as:

```
alias rm~='find . -name "*~" -type f -exec /bin/rm -fv -- {} +'
```

The `-type f` option so as to find only files (not directories, links, etc.), the `-v` option to `rm` so as to be verbose (prints out what it's deleting). The `+` at the end so that `find` runs `rm` with all the found files (spawns only one instance of `rm`, instead of one per file).

Now from `man bash`:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Instead of an alias, it's better to use a function: comment your alias in the `.bash_aliases` file (i.e., put a `#` in front of that line), and in the file `.bashrc`, put this *function* (anywhere in the file, at the end is fine):

```
rm~() {
    find . -name "*~" -type f -exec /bin/rm -fv -- {} +
}
```

Also, as the other answer mentions, you can use the `-delete` command to find. In this case, your `rm~` function will be:

```
rm~() {
    find . -name "*~" -type f -printf "Removing file %p\n" -delete
}
```

In fact, you can make a cool function that will take an argument, say `--dry-run`, that will only output what it will delete:

```
rm~() {
    case "$1" in
    "--dry-run")
        find . -name "*~" -type f -printf "[dry-run] Removing file %p\n"
        ;;
    "")
        find . -name "*~" -type f -printf "Removing file %p\n" -delete
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unsupported option \`$1'. Did you mean --dry-run?"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Then use as:

```
rm~ --dry-run
```

to only show the files that will be deleted (but not delete them) and then

```
rm~
```

when you're happy with this.

Adapt and extend to your needs!

**Note.** You'll have to open a new terminal for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely, and **dry run** is extremely helpful.

Comment: `find -type f -name '*~' -delete` (weapon of choice, besides `git clean -dfx .`)

Comment: This is such an elegant solution, I had to login just to give you props.  +1 to you, my good fellow!

Answer (score 9):

`*~` gets expanded by the shell before it gets assigned to your alias. The actual assignment is:

```
alias rm~='find .name some~ file~ 1n.in~ -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f'
```

I suggest to use functions instead of aliases, these are much more powerful and easier to handle in regard with quotes.

While we are at it, remove the superfluous `.` (current directory is implied if no parameters are given) and stop abusing `xargs` since a `-delete` option already exist.

```
rm~() { find -name '*~' -ls -delete; }
```

The `-ls` option is optional, but adding it will show you which files have been deleted.

Comment: +1 Thanks! But where do I add this function?

Comment: @VinayakGarg You can add it to your `.bash_aliases` too, but I usually put them straight in my `.bashrc`.